# Detached head does not disappear by creating branch. Why?

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I am always falling into detached head state I don't know why. And still not able to find a good way to get out of it. Some time I was thinking that it is sufficient to create branch when in detached head, but this doesn't help, HEAD remains detached:

```
>git branch
 (HEAD detached at af34e34)
 master

>git branch detachedhead20160610

>git branch
 (HEAD detached at af34e34)
 detachedhead20160610
 master

>git branch detachedhead20160610
Fatal: A branch named 'detachedhead20160610' already exists.

>git branch detachedhead20160610-2

>git branch
 (HEAD detached at af34e34)
 detachedhead20160610
 detachedhead20160610-2
 master
```

I.e. new branches just added without curing detached head state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion arises from not knowing what the `git branch` command does.  From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> Note that this will create the new branch, but it will not switch the working tree to it; use "git checkout " to switch to the new branch.

In other words, when you did `git branch detachedhead20160610`, you *created* a new branch called `detachedhead20160610` but you did not *switch* to that branch, hence Git still reported you as being in a detached head state.  Instead, you have two options:

```
git branch detachedhead20160610      # create a new branch
git checkout detachedhead20160610    # switch to that branch
```

or you can do it in one single command via:

```
git checkout -b detachedhead20160610 # create and switch to new branch
```